# Where does returnUrl come from in the Login(string returnUrl)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, post

I have a page that is requested like

```
/Bundler/Index?bid=153981866a37428a91ac870fa5cb169e
```

that I've decided to redirect to the

```
/Account/Login
```

page if the user is not signed in. Also, however, I'd like that once the user signs in they are redirected back to that page.

I've tried to study the `Login` functions (I refuse to call functions "methods!" It reminds me of Java) from the ASP.NET MVC template and I  believe that the parameter `returnUrl` seen in the signatures

```
    //
    // GET: /Account/Login
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

is the URL that the user will be directed to if they successfully log in. However, I'm not sure how to pass in a value for `returnUrl`.

On the `/Account/Login` page

the form

```
<form action="/Account/Login" class="form-horizontal" method="post" role="form">
```

does not look like it contains any inputs that correspond to the parameter `returnUrl` because there are none with that name.

So, how do I call, for instance,

```
Login("/Bundler/Index?bid=153981866a37428a91ac870fa5cb169e")
```

??

Comment: In the query string.

Comment: `action="/Account/Login?returnUrl=myencodedurl"`

Comment: So I've now tried putting `if (!Request.IsAuthenticated) Response.Redirect("/Account/Login?returnUrl="+Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);` on the `Bundler` page and it does indeed redirect me to the `Login` page and set the `form`'s action appropriately, but it's still redirecting to the home page after the login. Am I missing something?

Comment: @user4905335 Can you show us how you implement the `return Redirect()` call in your Login post action? (Please edit it into your question)

Comment: @Silvermind It's not my implementation; it's what came with the template. I'll post it.

Comment: Verify with the debugger... Is your URL accepted by the `RedirectToLocal()`, does it even get there?

Comment: Instead of meddling with he Login code, why don't you put an [Authorized] attribute on the Bundler class or Bundler.Index action? It's all built-in.